Hubspot Post Search API
How can I make a Hubspot API post call on search endpoint with the following:
A filter :
 {
      "filters": [
        {
          "propertyName": "lastmodifieddate",
          "operator": "GT",
          "value": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }

A limit:       {  "limit": 100}
Pagination:   ?
{"properties":["hs_analytics_average_page_views, hs_analytics_first_referrer, etc.... "]  (I may have up to 400 properties I am attempting to retrieve.
How would I make this call on postman?

This worked for me  in postman:Post http  url: https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search
body:  {
      "filters": [
        {
          "propertyName": "lastmodifieddate",
          "operator": "GT",
          "value": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "limit":20,
      "after":20,
      "properties":["hs_analytics_average_page_views"," hs_analytics_first_referrer"," hs_analytics_first_timestamp"," hs_analytics_first_touch_converting_campaign",....list fieldnames]
}

